# Always the same, wrong Error Code: "Oops, an error occurred! Class '2' not found"

Tags: typo3, flux, typo3-9.x

I am setting up a homepage with typo3 9.5.5, flux/fluidpages and vhs. Now always when i have some code error (syntax error for example) the Frontent show the Error "`Oops, an error occurred! Class '2' not found`", even when its obvious that it has nothing to do with a class 2. 
I have no Classes-Folder in my custom Extension and no idea where it want a Class 2..

The full Error Code is "`Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Class '2' not found | Error thrown in file /home/staff/typo3/typo3_src-9.5.5/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php in line 3667.`"

The big Problem is, this Error always show up when an error happen, even when the typo3 is almost fresh and it doesnt matter what error it is. Tried to up/downgrade flux and fluidpages.

Can someone help me with this please?
When someone need some code for helping me, just say it.

Comment: Did you include all required static templates?

Comment: Deactivate all custom extensions and test again. Never seen this kind of error, should be a problem in an extension.

Comment: maybe you have found an error in the errorhandler. Nevertheless try to update to the latest version (currently: 9.5.8) to eliminate already fixed errors.

Comment: OK i've found it. :)
my my my it was a syntax error in config.contentObjectExceptionHandler. it was set to... 2! Well, of course setting it to zero solved all my problems. 
Such a little number and so much confusion.. 
Got it by deactivating all static templates.
Thank you for helping!

Comment: Yes - the contentObjectExceptionHandler Set to 1 is default behavior and 0 is the correct setting if you want to see errors and stack trace in front end.